# Where can I find the PDF syntax for texorpdfstring?

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, pdf

I use `\texorpdfstring` for section commands, but how do I find the PDF syntax? For instance, I recently learned about `\texttwosuperior` just by chance. Is there a reference for similar symbols?

Comment: The command `\texttwosuperior` is found in the indispensible [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive).  The command `\texorpdfstring` comes from the `hyperref` package.  Neither deal with 'PDF syntax' as I understand the phrase; perhaps you could elaborate on your question?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Dear @jon, thanks for a useful comment. I've read more in the hyperref manual, and now I understand it much better!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been solved in the comments